# Using ajax to render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

In my rails app I have a model `Song`. On one of the user's profile pages `user_music_path(@user)` I'm rendering all of their songs.

People can also like these songs, which is set up and working, I just want to use AJAX instead of page refreshes. The problem I'm having is when using ajax, I get the error `undefined local variable or method "song"` when I'm clicking the link "like".

Here is some of my code:

**User's Music Page views/users/music.html.erb**

```
...
<ul class="playlist list-group">
  <%= render @songs %>
</ul>
```

**views/songs/_song.html.erb**

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <p class="pull-right">
    <%= render :partial => 'songs/like_button', :locals => {:song => song} %>
    <%= render :partial => 'songs/likes', :locals => {:song => song} %>
  </p>
</li>
```

**views/songs/_like_button.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user.voted_on?(song) %>
  <%= link_to "Unlike", unlike_song_path(song), :method => :post, :remote => true %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Like", like_song_path(song), :method => :post, :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

**views/songs/_likes.html.erb**

```
<%= song.votes.count %>
```

**views/songs/like.js.coffee**

```
$("p.pull-right").html('<%= render :partial => "songs/like_button", :locals => {:song => song} %><%= render :partial => "songs/likes", :locals => {:song => song} %>');
```

**controllers/songs_controller.rb**

```
def like
  begin
    @vote = current_user.vote_for(@song = Song.find(params[:id]))
    @vote.save
    respond_with @song.user, :location => user_music_path(@song.user)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    redirect_to @song
  end
end
```

And as mentioned earlier, the `:like` action worked perfectly before I starting using AJAX. I've also added `respond_to :html, :js` to my `songs_controller`. And the error I get when I try to like the song is `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method "song" for #<#<Class:0x000001028de9d0>:0x00000106ecd9f0>):`

Answer (score 1):

Where you have

```
<a href="<%= song.audio %>"><%= song.name %></a>
```

try instead

```
<a href="<%= @song.audio %>"><%= @song.name %></a>
```

And do the same with your `link_to` paths and your `render` calls.

Comment: Since I'm using the partial "_song.html.erb", I am calling render on a song variable of class `Song`, therefore I can still use the local variable `song` instead of `@song`

Comment: As long as you do this: `{:song => @song}`

Comment: If I do that, it changes every song's like_button on that page when I try to like one song.

Answer (score 0):

Do `rake routes` and use of of them for the link, e.g. (pseudo-code) `link_to 'song', song_audio_path`

Comment: That's not the issue at hand here. The issue is not the link to the song's audio, the issue is getting the proper partial to render with the local variable `song` when the song is liked/unliked.